# How to disable Windows 7 Hyperthreading

Tags: android, windows

So I need to disable hyperthreading on Windows for the purposes of HAXM instalation for Android emulator, but i cant find it anywhere. I've looked under the Turn Window Features on and off i couldn't find it. Is there any ther way to disable this feautre through a command line or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Hyper threading is enabled/disabled in my, and most likely your systems BIOS.  You'll need to reboot, go into your BIOS (by pressing Del or F11.. there should be instructions as the computer boots) and change the setting.